# Right-triangle, prove $cxy=v^3$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, rectangles

> In the right-triangle $\Delta ABC\;(\measuredangle BCA=90^{\circ})$ $\overline{CD}\;(|CD|=v)$ is the altitude on the edge $\overline{AB}\;(|AB|=c)$. $x$ and $y$ are perpendicular to the edges $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{BC}$ respectively. Prove $cxy=v^3$.

I was wondering if there are efficient methods that don't necessarily rely on Euclid's theorem for triangle or trigonometry.

Here is my approach:

Let $F\in\overline{AC}$ s.t.$|DF|=x$ and let $E\in\overline{BC}$ s.t. $|DG|=y$.

$$AC\perp DF\;\&\;AC\perp BC\implies DF\parallel BC$$
$$CD\perp BC\;\&\; BC\perp AC\implies CD\parallel AC$$
$CFDG$ is a rectangle.$\implies v^2=x^2+y^2$
$$\Delta ADF\sim\Delta FDC\sim\Delta EDB\sim ECD$$
Let $|AD|=p$ and $|BD|=q$
$$\frac{x}{p}=\frac{y}{v}\implies p=\frac{x}{y}v$$
$$\frac{y}{q}=\frac{x}{v}\implies q=\frac{y}{x}v$$
$$c=p+q=\frac{x}{y}v+\frac{y}{x}v=\frac{v^3}{xy}\implies cxy=v^3$$

Picture:
[image]
$$Q.E.D.$$

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the right triangles BCD and CDG are similar. So are the right triangles ACD and CDF. Then,

$$\frac xv = \frac v{BC}, \>\>\>\>\> \frac yv = \frac v{AC}$$

Recognize

$$Area_{ABC} = \frac 12 vc =\frac12 BC\cdot AC $$

and multiply the two equations to arrive at

$$cxy =v^3$$